# How can I cancel the setTimeout time in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I have created an application in which when a button is pressed the clock time starts. If nothing is done after 23 seconds (23000) is set to 0 and the state is changed (this.state.user) .This is correct.

If you click on the element again, I need the 23 seconds (23000) to be zeroed and the Timeout cleaned. Because if there is still some time left in the timeout, the item closes automatically.

I tried "clearTimeout (this.change);
clearInterval (this.change); "but it doesn't work, I don't know how to cancel this time.

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.change = null;

        this.state = {
            usuario: true,
            timeElapsed: 0,
            adminOrWrap: true,
        };

        ["descansoAdminWrap", "otrosDescansos",].forEach((method) => {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
        });
    }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.notInCall === false && this.props.notInCall && this.state.usuario === true) {
            this.descansoAdminWrap(prevProps, prevState);
       }
   }

    descansoAdminWrap(prevProps){
        var usuarioAdminOrWrapFalse=  this.state.usuario && this.props.adminOrWrap === false;
        var notInCallFalseUsuario= this.props.notInCall === false && this.state.usuario
        //mostrar y ocultar el descanso de 'tiempo administrativo' y 'wrap time'
        if(this.state.usuario && this.props.notInCall){
            this.setState({
                usuario: false,
                timeElapsed: 0,
            });
            clearTimeout(this.change);
            clearInterval(this.change);
            if(prevProps.notInCall === false){
                this.handleAdminOrWrap(false)
                this.setState({
                    usuario: false,
                    timeElapsed: 0,
                });
                this.change = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        usuario: true,
                        notInCall: true,
                    });
                    this.handleAdminOrWrap(true)
                }, 23000)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: clearTimeout is the way to do it. check your 'if conditions' if they are executing properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearTimeout` is used for `setTimeout`, and `clearInterval` for `setInterval`.

So using a `clearInterval` here isn't going to help.

I would check if you are actually call the `clearTimeout` with a `console.log` inside your `if` condition when you expect to do so. Especially when you are modifying the `state.usuario` value to `false` the first time around, which would prevent you to clear the condition again.